# Flutter: Widget that comes in by slide-transition is not clickable. Why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using slide transition to move a button from partially the outside to the inside of the screen.

After the transition is completed, the button is not clickable. Just a small part of the button which is initially inside the screen is clickable.

Animation works fine.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Here is a summary of my code:

```
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: Row(
        children: [
         ...,
         ...,

         // This button initially stays outside of the screen but small part of that.
         OutlinedButton(onPressed: () { print('object'); },
               child: Text('Start')
         ),
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to this problem.

The problem was occurring because I was trying to move a button from outside of the viewport to inside using slide transition. I thought that the button is supposed to become clickable after getting inside. But it's not happening this way and I don't know why yet.

So I decided to use a fade effect instead of sliding the button from the outside and the problem rather solved.

Comment: Did you find a solution with the SlideTransition? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @LukeIrvin No, I just rather changed the problem.